# Ensure that every column in a matrix has at least `e` non-zero elements

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

I would like to ensure that each column in a matrix has at least `e` non-zero elements, and for each column that does not randomoly replace zero-valued elements with the value `y` until the column contains `e` non-zero elements. Consider the following matrix where some columns have 0, 1 or 2 elements. After the operation, each column should have at least `e` elements of value `y`.

**before**

```
tensor([[0, 7, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 4]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

**after, `e = 2`**

```
tensor([[y, 7, 0, y],
        [y, 0, y, 0],
        [0, 1, y, 4]], dtype=torch.int32)
```

I have a very slow and naive loop-based solution that works:

```
def scatter_elements(x, e, y):
  for i in range(x.shape[1]):
    col = x.data[:, i]
    num_connections = col.count_nonzero()
    to_add = torch.clip(e - num_connections, 0, None)
    indices = torch.where(col == 0)[0]
    perm = torch.randperm(indices.shape[0])[:to_add]
    col.data[indices[perm]] = y
```

Is it possible to do this without loops? I've thought about using `torch.scatter` and generate an `index` array first, but since the number of elements to be added varies per column, I see no straightforward way to use it. Any suggestions or hints would be greatly appreciated!

**Edit**: swapped indices and updated title and description based on comment.

Comment: You use `col` to index rows in this example which is fairly confusing, and your use of "elements" is non-standard: an element can have a value of 0. What you really mean is "non-zero elements". Based on what the code chunk does currently, I believe the appropriate description is: Ensure that each ROW  in `x` has at least `e` non-zero elements, and for each row that does not randomly replace zero-valued elements with the value `y` until the row contains `e` non-zero elements.

Comment: @DerekG thanks, I have updated the description and code correspondingly (column-based constraints). Unfortunately I swapped rows/columns when refactoring the code into the MWE.

Answer (score 1):

In the case where you care only that each column has at least `e` elements and not EXACTLY `e` elements, you can do it without a loop. The key is that in this case, we can create an array with every non-zero value replaced, and then sample e values from this array for each column.

For convenience let `x.shape = [a,b]`

1. Create an array `replace` with every value replaced (i.e. every 0 replaced with `y`).
2. Create a random array of same size as `x`.
3. Use `torch.topk` to get the `k` largest random numbers per column. This is used to get `k` random indices for each column (in your case `k` = `e`). Provided that `x` is non-negative integer, you can add `x` to the random array before the `topk` operation to ensure that the existing non-zero elements are selected first; this ensures that no more than `e` connections are added.
4. Replace the indexed values per row with the values from `replace`.

```
def scatter_elements(x,e,y):
  x = x.float()
  # 1. replace has same shape as x and has all 0s replaced with y
  replace = torch.where(x > 0 , x, torch.ones(x.shape)*y)

  # 2-3. get random indices per column
  randn = torch.rand(x.shape)
  if True: # True if you don't want the modification to ever itself assign more than e elements in a column a non-zero value
      randn += x # assumes x is non-negative integer

  ind = torch.topk(randn,e,dim = 0)[1] # first return is values, second return is indices

  # create a second index to indicate which column each index in ind corresponds to
  col_ind = torch.arange(x.shape[1]).unsqueeze(0).expand(ind.shape)

  # 4. Index x with ind and col_ind and set these values to the corresponding values in replace
  ind = ind.reshape(-1)         # flatten into 1D array so we can use to index row
  col_ind = col_ind.reshape(-1) # flatten into 1D array so we can use to index column
  x[ind,col_ind] = replace[ind,col_ind]
  
  return x
```

In my limited timing tests, the vectorized solution was about 5-6x faster than the original looping solution.

Comment: Thank you! You mentioned that having *exactly* `e` elements is problematic. My solution adds as many elements as required to reach exactly `e` connections and not more. This is the intended and required behaviour. Is this what you refer to?

Comment: Yes. You will have difficulty / it may not be possible to use a vectorized approach in this case because the number of replacements is variable based on the stored values. (In the solution above, the number of replacements per column is always e). If you can ensure that all non-zero values in `x` fall within some range, then you would be able to use this characteristic to always select the non-zero elements of `x` first to be included in the replacement, which would give you exactly `e` elements.

Comment: Also, what is the desired behavior if elements in `x` have negative values?

Comment: I added a fix for the case where all elements in x are integer-valued and non-negative

Comment: The intended behaviour for negative values is that they should be treated the same way as non-zero positive values.

Comment: I've managed to come up with a vectorized version of my loop-based approach, see my answer. Thanks for giving it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

After some more experimentation with my original loop-based solution I realized that I was already pretty close to a vectorized version:

```
def scatter_elements_vec(x, e, y):
    rand = torch.rand_like(x, dtype=torch.float)
    rand[x != 0] = torch.inf
    num_connections = x.count_nonzero(0)
    to_add = torch.clip(e - num_connections, 0, None)
    mask = torch.argsort(rand, 0) < to_add
    x[mask] = y
```